# JS Conflict in Twitter-Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am having an issue with a little bit of JS I am using and wondering if anyone else has encountered this or could suggest a work around?

So my script is to animate my anchor links so they slide around nicely but it is conflicting with the controls of the Bootstrap 3 carousel.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
          if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 500);
          return false;
      });
  });
```

And the controls on the carousel use the id of the carrousel name so uses the # so of course it navigated down to the carousel and not actually switch the content inside.

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>

<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
```

Any suggestions would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make any other attribute to locate direction of slider, like data-target="#myCarousel",

and make link href="javascript:;".

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="javascript:;" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
```

carousel js script: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L188-L193

these lines should give a general idea.